# htaccess rewrite changes for localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get this website to work on my local machine but the links no longer work due to .htaccess file settings which I've been unsuccessfully trying to alter. The page content is in a database, and the links look like

```
<a href="<?=$linkLocations?>" id="bestLoc"<?=$activeBest?>>Best Locations</a>
```

that variable is defined as a global as

```
$linkLocations = $URL . '/best-locations';
```

and bestLocations is actually a .php file that queries the database.  The .htaccess file is showing a lot of rewrite rules, here is the complete file

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript



ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000

ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000

ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000

ExpiresByType image/png A2592000

ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000

ExpiresByType text/css A604800

ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800

ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000

<FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">

Header set Cache-Control "public"

</FilesMatch>



RewriteEngine on
fafaf


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ communities/index.php?community=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ communities/index.php?community=$1 [NC]



RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ communities/index.php?community=$1&commPage=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ communities/index.php?community=$1&commPage=$2 [NC]



RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ communities/index.php?community=$1&commPage=$2&model=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^communities/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ communities/index.php?community=$1&commPage=$2&model=$3 [NC]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ subpage.php?page=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ subpage.php?page=$1 [NC]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ subpage.php?page=$1&sp=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ subpage.php?page=$1&sp=$2 [NC]



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ subpage.php?page=$1&sp=$2&spd=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/$ subpage.php?page=$1&sp=$2&spd=$3 [NC]
```

- I haven't altered the rewrites from the live version.
- I'm accessing the URL via localhost/bentley/ via WAMP
- The live site is http://bentleyhomes.com
- The directory structure of the website doesn't have the linked pages,
  but rather php files outputting database data

I know I'm missing a lot here and probably out of my depth but if anyone could point me in a general direction I would be grateful; I've spent a morning on htaccess tutorials but this is still a bit tough for me.

Comment: So....what exactly doesn't work? And if you're not sure, you should post your entire .htaccess file contents instead of what you might think would be the problem. :)

Comment: And the a sample url that you are using to access your local server

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)| I"m not familiar with this construction, is that a typo or is it actually what it says? It's a lot easier when making paths to just make them to /, that way you don't have to worry about the server local or domain name of the site. This sounds to me more like you have an issue setting up your local virtual host configuration than anything with a rewrite rule.

Comment: What is this line `fafaf` in your .htaccess? Where is this .htaccess located on your localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ subpage.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

And now (after your edit), without :

```
fafaf
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```